# Swift Combine: Do asynchronous work in a Future?

Tags: swift, combine

I have an object called `ProcessorStack` which contains zero or more child `Processor` items. The `ProcessorStack` and the individual `Processor` objects each have only a single method:

`process(input: Value) -> Future<Value, Never>`

I would like the return value to be a `Future` rather than `AnyPublisher` to clearly indicate that the caller should only expect a single result to be emitted. Other objects only have access to the `ProcessorStack`, not its `Processor` children. Here's what I want to happen:

1. An object calls the `ProcessorStack`:

   ```
   stack.process(value: someValue).sink { result in
       // Do something with the result
   }.store(in: &subscriptions)
   ```
2. The `ProcessorStack` chains all of its child `Processor` objects together using a reduce operation and returns the final result via the `Future`:

   ```
   func process(value: Value) -> Future<Value, Never> {
       guard !childProcessors.isEmpty else {
           return Future { $0(.success(value)) }
       }
       let just = Just(value).eraseToAnyPublisher()
       childProcessors.reduce(just) { (publisher, processor) -> AnyPublisher<Value, Never> in
           publisher.flatMap { processor.process(value: $0).eraseToAnyPublisher() }
       }
       // Here's where I'm lost.
   }
   ```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to execute the asynchronous reduce chain and then return the result as a `Future`. If I wrap the whole reduce operation in a `Future` initializer, I'm left holding an `AnyPublisher<Value, Never>` which I somehow have to get to execute and then the result of that get passed to the `Future`'s completion closure. I can't `sink` it inside the `Future`'s closure, because I have to hold on to the cancellable returned from that or the whole process immediately halts. I can't FlatMap the result into a Future, because that has the type `FlatMap<AnyPublisher<Value, Never>, Future<Value, Never>>`. I can accomplish all of this if I just make the outer return type `AnyPublisher<Value, Never>`, but I was really hoping to have the `Future` semantics for subscribers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The premise of what you're trying to do is wrong. `Future`, though it can only return at most a single result, doesn't semantically stand for that. It's just a specific type of a publisher.

You should be returning an `AnyPublisher` at the function boundary, and not try to avoid it, which would make your code more robust to changes (e.g. what if you needed to wrap the `Future` in a `Deferred`? - a common practice)

```
process(value: Value) -> AnyPublisher<Value, Never> {
   ...
}
```

And if a subscriber can only handle a single result, they could simply ensure that with `first()`:

```
process(value)
    .first()
    .sink {...}
    .store(in: &storage)
```

---

But if you insist, you *could* use a `.sink` inside `Future`'s closure, if the closure captured the reference to the `AnyCancellable` and released it on completion:

```
process(value: Value) -> Future<Value, Never> {
    guard !childProcessors.isEmpty else {
        return Future { $0(.success(value)) }
    }
    let just = Just(value).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    let combined = childProcessors.reduce(just) { (publisher, processor) -> AnyPublisher<Value, Never> in
        publisher.flatMap { processor.process(value: $0).eraseToAnyPublisher() }
    }

    var c: AnyCancellable? = nil
    return Future { promise in
        c = combined.sink(receiveCompletion: { 
            withExtendedLifetime(c){}; c = nil 
        }) {
            promise(.success($0))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your eloquent response and for letting me know that `withExtendedLifetime` exists.